# Is a representative sample necessary to assess construct validity?

Tags: factor-analysis, psychometrics, validity, item-response-theory

To generalize results to a greater population, a representative sample is necessary. In developing a psychometrically valid instrument, via confirmatory factor analysis or item response theory, we are interested in understanding the underlying relationships among items, and whether they measure a unified construct with sufficient accuracy and precision. When we conduct such a study, we are not interested in the resulting respondent scores; the respondents serve as a source of data to test whether the structure exists as we hypothesize.

I am looking for various views on whether or not it is necessary to have a representative sample to conduct such a validity study. Measurement invariance or differential item functioning - a key part of establishing validity - requires different subgroups, but having subgroups does not mean the sample overall is representative of a population. My question comes from a practical angle - oftentimes, when developing a new instrument or assessment, it can be challenging to find a representative sample to field it on without already having it validated, kind of a Catch-22. If you are going to make the case that a representative sample is not necessary, please provide citations if possible.

Comment: Isn't a questionnaire/test being developed always for on some population and for some population? One would not expect a test for humans be valid for elephants. But I feel your question is about whether the sample on which the test is developed should have the same subgroup ratio as in the population. E.g., 49%/51% male/female, and not, say, 60/40. Then the answer might be: if you goal in future is to test just groups from general population, 49/50 sample is required. If your goal will be to be able to test individuals from subgroups, you must validate for each such subgroup.

Comment: `but having subgroups does not mean the sample overall is representative of a population`. If each subsample is reasonably representative of its subpopulation then the combined stratified sample is representative of the population, except for the structure (ratio), but that can be accounted by weighting.